# Flex box -- How to arrange last item in the vacant space of above div section

Tags: css, flexbox

Please check this code for more information. Please refer the above image for better clarity. In the right side section of the image you can see in the last row have two items and the second row have one vacant section, I have to move one of the list item into the vacant position.

```
<style>
.main {
    max-width: 900px;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: aqua;
}

.main_inner {
    display: flex;
    border: 1px solid black;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.list {
    min-width: 250px;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    background-color: black;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 15px;
}
```

```
<div class="main">
<div class="main_inner">
    <div class="list">List</div>
    <div class="list">List</div>
    <div class="list">List</div>
    <div class="list">List</div>
    <div class="list">List</div>
    <div class="list">List</div>
</div>
<div class="main_inner">
    <div class="list">List</div>
    <div class="list">List</div>
    <div class="list">List</div>
    <div class="list">List</div>
    <div class="list">List</div>
</div>
<div class="main_inner">
    <div class="list">List</div>
    <div class="list">List</div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Css-grid would be a better solution than flexbox - regardless neither can move an element from one container to another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`display: contents` can solve this but it's like you no more have the `.main_inner` element so you can no more apply styles to it.

```css
.main {
  max-width: 900px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: aqua;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.main_inner {
  display: contents;
}

.list {
  min-width: 250px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="main_inner">
    <div class="list">List</div>
    <div class="list">List</div>
    <div class="list">List</div>
    <div class="list">List</div>
    <div class="list">List</div>
    <div class="list">List</div>
  </div>
  <div class="main_inner">
    <div class="list">List</div>
    <div class="list">List</div>
    <div class="list">List</div>
    <div class="list">List</div>
    <div class="list">List</div>
  </div>
  <div class="main_inner">
    <div class="list">List</div>
    <div class="list">List</div>
  </div>
```